# Application level cache in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, caching, application-layer

Is there any thing call application level cache objects in codeIgniter? Just like in Spring (Java EE) web applications? Further in Spring if we use ehcache then more options like FIFO,LIFO etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible and is handled using the [Web Page Caching functionality - see user guide link here for details](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/caching.html). This enables you to cache an entire page and skip a large amount of the framework processing for that page.

If you are looking for finer controlled caches then you are looking to install something like APC or Memcache in to PHP and then run one of [the caching drivers](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/caching.html). This enables you also to cache specific parts of each request.